# How to call all native constructors (rule of five)

Tags: c++

I wrote my own Matrix class. To test its constructors and operators, I need to call each one. How can i do this? Now called move operator and copy constructor, but still need move constructor and assignment operator

```
 Matrix(const Matrix &other) : data(new T[other.rows * other.cols]), rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols)
        {
            std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i)
            {
                data[i] = other.data[i];
            }
        }

        Matrix &operator=(const Matrix<T> &other)
        {
            std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;
            if (&other == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }

            if (rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
            {
                throw std::logic_error("Error assigning matrices of different sizes");
            }

            data = (static_cast<T *>(operator new[](sizeof(T) * rows * cols, static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T)))));
            rows = other.rows;
            cols = other.cols;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i)
            {
                data[i] = other.data[i];
            }

            return *this;
        }

        Matrix(Matrix &&other) noexcept : data(other.data), rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols)
        {
            std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;
        }

        Matrix &operator=(Matrix<T> &&other)
        {
            std::cout << "move operator" << std::endl;
            if (&other == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }

            if (rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
            {
                throw std::logic_error("Error assigning matrices of different sizes");
            }

            clean();

            std::swap(data, other.data);
            std::swap(rows, other.rows);
            std::swap(cols, other.cols);

            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;

            return *this;
        }
```

Here are the constructor calls, how to call all the available constructors in general?
main.cpp

```
Matrix<int> mat1(3, 3);
Matrix<int> mat2(3, 3);
mat1.fillMatrix();
mat2.fillMatrix();

mat2 = std::move(mat1);

Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1;
mat3.printMatrix();
Matrix<int> mat4(mat1);
```

Comment: tactical note: Once you've moved from an object it is in a safe but unspecified state, so using `mat1` after `mat2 = std::move(mat1);` can cause problems.

Comment: Side note: Don't just call the functions once. Call each function enough times to make sure you have exercises all of the paths through the function.

Comment: @user4581301 -- a moved-from object is in whatever state the code leaves it in. In this case, apparently, the result is a 0x0 `Matrix` object with no data. The "safe but unspecified state" is a gloss on the requirements for library types in the C++ standard. It's not a requirement for user-defined types.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what `clean()` would do that would also require explicitly nulling the `data` member and setting the dimensions to 0.

Comment: @PeteBecker I should have been less generic in that comment. Using the copy constructor to copy the moved from object in this case will result in an object with a matrix of 0 size, a potentially nasty surprise.

Comment: @user4581301 -- having an empty state is not an unreasonable design; of course, all of the code that deals with those types has to allow for that possibility.

Comment: @user4581301  In this case, I suspect `Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1;` was a mistake and OP meant to copy `mat2`.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I'm not going to speculate on the user's intent. The big point is they can't expect `mat3` to be a 3x3 matrix in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
Matrix<int> mat1(3, 3);                           // not shown constructor
Matrix<int> mat2(mat1);                           // copy constructor
Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1;                          // copy constructor
mat3 = mat1;                                      // operator=(const Matrix&)
Matrix<int> mat4(std::move(Matrix<int>(3, 3)));   // move constructor
Matrix<int> mat5 = std::move(Matrix<int>(3, 3));  // move constructor
mat5 = Matrix<int>(3, 3);                         // operator=(Matrix&&)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/eoodeoK6h

---

Explicit `std::move` is used for avoiding elisions.

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason the move constructor was not called. Everyone else volunteered

Comment: It's not called because of mandatory copy elision.

Comment: `Matrix<int> mat4(Matrix<int>(3, 3));` does not call the move constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use casts and `std::move` here:

```
Matrix<int> source;
Matrix<int> target(std::move(source)); // move constructor
```

```
Matrix<int> source;
Matrix<int> target;
target = std::move(source); // move assignment operator
```

```
Matrix<int> source;
Matrix<int> target(static_cast<Matrix<int> const&>(source)); // copy constructor
```

```
Matrix<int> source;
Matrix<int> target;
target = static_cast<Matrix<int> const&>(source); // copy assignment
```

Note that technically the casts to const references are unnecessary, but with the cast you would also be able to prevent another overload taking `Matrix<int>&` as parameter from being applicable.

Note: If you write unit tests, it may be a good idea to add `static_assert`s checking for the existance of the special member functions.

```
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<Matrix<int>>, "Matrix<int> is not move constructible");
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<Matrix<int>>, "Matrix<int> is not move assignable");
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Matrix<int>>, "Matrix<int> is not copy constructible");
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable_v<Matrix<int>>, "Matrix<int> is not copy assignable");
```

This way you'd get a compiler error, if you got one of the signatures wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Copy and move constructors are called when you initializing new object.
Difference between move and copy is what argument you use to initialize it. If it tempory or special std::move function is used than move ctor would be called(not in all cases though), otherwise copy constructor. For example:

```cpp
Matrix<int> mat1(3,3);
Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1; //cp-ctor
Matrix<int> mat4 = std::move(mat1);//mv-ctor
Matrix<int> mat5(mat1);//cp-ctor full equivalent of second line
Matrix<int> mat6 = someFunctionReturningMatrixByCopy(); //mv-ctor
```

Comment: @273K It's state depends solely on how you write your move constructor. OP's constructor zeroes the matrix.

Comment: @273K -- it's not in an unspecified state. It's in exactly the state that the move operation leaves it in, which looks like it's a 0x0 object with no data. That's not an unreasonable design, as long as the rest of the code is aware of this possibility.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe -- a moved from object is no longer in a valuable (valid?) state **if** that's what moving from it does. In the code in the question that's **not the case**. Technical decisions should not be based on generic fears, nor on "English semantic discussion". They should be based on analysis of **what the code does**. If "consensus" tells you that a `Matrix` object in the code in the question is not in a valid state after being moved from the "consensus" is simply wrong, because that's **not** what the code does.